# SQL server v17 : how to convert smalldatetime value to datetime

Tags: sql-server, casting, datetime-format

I used following query to insert the data :

```
 CASE(isdate([Date])) 
            WHEN 1 THEN [date] 
            WHEN 0 THEN cast(substring([Date],0,5) - 2 as smalldatetime)
            ELSE [date] END
```

Now, datetime column has date in smalldatetime format. How to convert smalldatetime formatted date to datetime format whereas column type is datetime.

Example: For Numeric date `41298` it resulted into `1911-04-21 00:00:00` but actual expected result was `2013-01-26 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Have you tried storing the value in smalldatetime into datetime column? i think it will be managed by it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Date]) = 1
      THEN DATEADD(day, CAST([Date] as int), '1899-12-31')
      WHEN iSDATE([Date]) = 1
      THEN CAST([date] as smalldatetime)
 END)
```

The value 41298 looks like an Excel formatted date.  These start counting from the last day of 1899.

Comment: The Excel value was my original thought as well, but it is off one day from the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your given value and it convert to expected result please have a look;

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(41298 AS smalldatetime) AS DATE) AS Date
SELECT CAST(41298 AS smalldatetime) AS Date
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is DateAdd

```
Select DateAdd(DAY,41298,'1900-01-01')
```

Returns

```
2013-01-26 00:00:00.000
```